# Cocoa - Making a NSTextView smaller than its enclosing NSScrollView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a NSTextView inside a NSScrollView. I would like it to keep its margins smaller than the enclosing NSScrollView to make the text more readable without changing its tab rtf settings. I have tried to make a referencing outlet in IB to the NSClipView and doing this :

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSClipView myClipView;
```

then in the implementation of awakeFromNib

```
NSEdgeInsets myInsets = [self.myClipView contentInsets];

myInsets.left = 25;
myInsets.right = 25;

[self.myClipView setAutomaticallyAdjustsContentInsets:NO];

[self.myClipView setContentInsets:myInsets];
```

but I get no results unless I unclick Auto resize subviews for the NSClipView in IB, but then the NSTextView does not get resized properly any more.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: also it seems my code is only available in 10.10 and later, is there any solution that also works before on 10.8+ ?

Comment: Have you tried working with autolayout and the constraints you can set in IB?  It is often very frustrating, but you should be able to set fixed constraints to the enclosing view right in IB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-[NSTextView setTextContainerInset:]` looks like it would do what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot this did the trick also that, unfortunately, it does not work well with the height because it does et the inset of the textview so there is space on the bottom and on the top but not when scrolling.